# Can't see the borders at all and the footer shows no color

Tags: html, css

my borders are not showing seems like they do not exist and after running through the code for a hour i still couldn't find the problem.

and my footer doesn't show it's div background-color

hope someone can help me, thanks :)

this is the website you can see the code in the top right button "change view" -> "editor view"

```css
#background-body{
background-color:#e6e6fa;
border-style:solid;
border-color:silver;
border-width:70px;
margin:50px, 120px, 30px ,120px;
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="background-body">
```

Comment: correct the margin first `margin:50px, 120px, 30px ,120px; ` there is no `,`

Answer (score 1):

First of all add a fixed heigth to your container, fix your margin syntax and you can come up with something like this:

```css
#background-body{
background-color:#e6e6fa;
border-style:solid;
border-color:silver;
border-width:10px;
height:100px;
margin:50px 120px 30px 120px;
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="background-body"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct your margin property. margin property won't work with comma separated values.

```css
#background-body{
        background-color:#e6e6fa;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:silver;
        border-width:70px;
        margin:50px 120px 30px 120px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="background-body">
```